# Chrome address bar causes scroll on my mobile webpage

Tags: css, nuxt.js

I'm creating a mobile-first webapp using NuxtJS. The expected behavior is to have a page that takes up the entire screen without scroll. It works fine in development but when I try it out on a real device, the Chrome address bar causes a little scroll.

I've seen [this kind of advice](https://www.reddit.com/r/Frontend/comments/d1czwl/fix_for_100vh_with_mobile_address_bar_visible/ezl3o9k?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) to add `height: 100%` to the `html` and `body` tag.

Even with this, it seems like my display is overflowing the page when the address bar is shown.

How could I fix this without hiding the address bar (seems like a hacky solution, CSS would be prefered)?

```
html,
body,
#__nuxt,
#__layout {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi @kissu, so far, I didn't get to the expected result with it. Nothing that I've tried seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue is well-known and pretty annoying indeed.
There are a lot of possible hacks for this on the Web and a new unit like `vh` but without the address bar issue is in the works.

In the meantime, the best solution yet is to try something like this

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
html {
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

As shown here: https://css-tricks.com/css-fix-for-100vh-in-mobile-webkit/

Comment: https://gist.github.com/theolavaux/aac0cf516814516e0c819a2d3642fffa I've tried this, but then another issue appears, my `margin: auto`s inside my pages stops working because I believe no explicit height is set on the body (I removed the `height: 100%` on the body)